# Modification Date on EXT4 files marked as Nov 29 1979

Tags: date, ext4, flac

I am running Linux Mint 20.2 64 bit Cinnamon and these are FLAC files that are failing an integrity test. The files seem to play fine. Could this be because the Modification date is wrong. The date created and last accessed appear to be correct. So I am asking two questions:

1. Is this incorrect modification date the reason the files are failing the integrity test? The test is run in the terminal with this command

   ```
   $ find ~/Music/ -type f -iname '*.flac' -print0 | 
       xargs --null flac -wst
   ```
2. Is there any easy way of changing the modification date en masse or do I need to do it file by file (there are 100s of such files)?

Comment: *an integrity test*: which integrity test?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: In this case, the `flac -wst` is the test. I am not certain about how `flac` determines integrity, however.

Comment: It decodes, but instead of piping the decoded samples into an audio system, it just discards them, that's why I'm surprised to hear "it plays fine". With what are you playing it, and what is your version libFLAC.so?

Answer (score 1):

First, Unix filesystems (FS) do not generally track the "creation time" (I say generally because there are now FS's that track the "birth" time). The "ctime" field from the stat() system call is *not* "(C)reation time" like in DOS/WIN, but rather it is the "inode (C)hange time"--the time the inode itself was last modified.

Second, if and how it affects any integrity check depends on the tool you use. Most tools will not consider any timestamps because timestamps change too often. If there is an integrity failure, it is more likely a real integrity failure--the files "play fine" because the CODEC simply discards bad data, which may not be significant enough to be noticeable by humans.

Related, the fact that you have so many bad timestamps suggests to me that the drive itself is failing, and resulting in corrupted data when it tries to "recover and relocate" a bad sector. Most modern drives support SMART failure detection methods, and you can install various SMART monitors and tools to check their status. I suggest you do this.

Third, `touch -- *.flac` should update them all at once to the current time. (Unless, of course, you have so many that they exceed the buffer that the shell creates for passing the list of file names. But that is another issue.)

Comment: Thanks. The files were copied off another drive which did die. I think that is the origin of the problem.SMART  quick test was fine for this present drive.I am not sure of the subtleties of file attributes but there are three entries in file properties (Nemo) one is Accessed, then there is Created and finally Modified. The first two entries appear correct the last entry is where the 1979 date stamp is. With regards to the touch command, is it possible to specify only those files with the Nov 29 1979 modification stamp. I am sorry if I am not understanding the nuances of file properties.

Comment: That would suggest that the inode entries were what was corrupted, where the file access and modification timestamps are stored. But the timestamps should not affect integrity tests, as they are part of the file system, _not_ the file (FLAC) data. And yes, `man touch` will give you the manual page for `touch` and all it's many options to control how/when/why/where/which/and if you want fries and a shake with that.